# not saving my excel file in the root directory

Tags: c#, asp.net

After executing the below part of code, file is not getting saved in the content folder. On the button click I am saving the excel file into the content folder of root directory.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        String fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName).ToLower();
        String[] allowedExtensions = { ".xls", ".xlsx", ".xlsm" };

        for (int i = 0; i < allowedExtensions.Length; i++)
        {
            if (fileExtension == allowedExtensions[i])
            {
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Content/") + FileUpload1.FileName);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("");
    }
}
```

Comment: So do you want it in the root directory, or in the Content folder?

Comment: either in the root directory or content folder of the solution.

Comment: I have just tested your code and it saved the file to the Content folder fine. Are you looking in the solution explorer or through File Explorer?

Comment: If you have checked for the file using File Explorer and you do not see it, then I would suggest checking your permissions on the folder?

Comment: Thank u MalvEarp, I was checking in solution explorer. It's working when I checked into file explorer.